What type of cashflow is each cashflow in a Leg
I have a quantlib Leg object for a mtm cross currency swap. It has coupons, redemption amounts for the effective and redemption dates as well as all the interim rebalancing mtm cashflows.
As I iterate over the cashflows in the leg is there a straight forward way to tell what type of cashflow I have at each iteration point.
e.g a function like cashflowtype() below :
for c in leg:
print(c.date(), c.amount(), c.cashflowtype())

Dimitri's answer on the question he linked is valid.  Also see https://www.implementingquantlib.com/2023/09/cross-currency-swaps.html for an example closer to your use case.
